# How to allow pdf files in .htaccess?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, pdf

I have this following codes in my htaccess file, but it doesn't allow pdf file to open, it will redirect to 404 page. how can I allow pdf files to open based on my following htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt\.pdf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|pdf|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I highly appreciate your help. Thank

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.